# Minimum average waiting time for customer orders

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-average-waiting-time/problem
Here is a link to a hackerrank problem. I was working on.
Its passing a few test cases and failing some. I have used the in built priority queue template in STL.
The code is as follows,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct customer
{
    long long arrTime;
    long long cookTime;
    long long index;
};
void swap(customer& a,customer& b)
{
    customer &temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
bool compare( customer& a, customer& b)
{
    return a.arrTime<b.arrTime;
}
struct Compare1
{
    bool operator()(customer a,customer b)
    {
        return a.cookTime>b.cookTime;
    }
};
struct Compare2
{
    bool operator()(customer a,customer b)
    {
        return a.arrTime>b.arrTime;
    }
};
int main()
{
    vector<customer>c;
    vector<bool>done;
    long long n;
    cin>>n;
    for(long long i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        customer cust;
        cin>>cust.arrTime;
        cin>>cust.cookTime;
        cust.index=i;
        c.push_back(cust);
        done.push_back(false);
    }
    sort(c.begin(),c.end(),compare);
    for(long long i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(c[i].arrTime==c[i+1].arrTime && c[i].cookTime>c[i].cookTime)
        {
            swap(c[i],c[i+1]);
        }
    }
    priority_queue<customer,vector<customer>,Compare1> waitList;
    vector<long long>tat(n);
    vector<long long>ct(n);

    //next step- priority queue work starts
    long long count=0;
    long long totalTime=0;

    long long i=0;
    while(count!=n)
    {
        while(i<n && c[i].arrTime<=totalTime)
        {
            waitList.push(c[i]);
            i++;
        }
        customer next;
        if(!waitList.empty())
        {
            next=waitList.top();
            //cout<<"Job "<<next.index<<endl;
            waitList.pop();
            totalTime+=next.cookTime;
            ct[next.index]=totalTime;
            done[next.index]=true;  
            count++;

        }
        else if(i<n)
        {
            next=c[i];
            //cout<<"Job "<<next.index<<endl;
            i++;
            totalTime+=next.cookTime;
            ct[next.index]=totalTime;
            done[next.index]=true;  
            count++;
        }

    }
    long long sum=0;
    for(long long i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        tat[i]=ct[i]-c[i].arrTime;
        sum+=tat[i];
    }
    cout<<sum/n;
    return 0;
}
```

I looked up an algorithm called non preemptive priority scheduling for this problem and implemented it. My doubt:
Is this scheduling algorithm the right one for the problem? I would like to know if there are any mistakes in my implementation of the scheduling algorithm.
Or any other algorithm to implement it.
Here is a description for the variable names,

tat array stands for total turnaround time of the jobs

ct array stands for completion time.

I have considered turn around time=waiting time for non preemptive priority scheduling.

done is just a flag array to indicate the process which are marked as done.

arrTime stands for arrival Time.

cookTime stands for cooking time (rather the burst time for the process in actual algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing the cases, where there are multiple jobs starting in the same time 
and all of them could be completed before the next job starts which is very small.

For example,

```
5
0 3
0 2
0 4
10 2
10 1
```

should enqeue first 3 items and process all of them before enqeuing other 2 items. This case will fail in your case.

**Other observation:**

The for loop for arranging the vector based in cooktime is not needed and coded wrongly.

```
for(long long i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    if(c[i].arrTime==c[i+1].arrTime && c[i].cookTime>c[i].cookTime)
    {
        swap(c[i],c[i+1]);
    }
}
```

It must be 'c[i].cookTime>c[i+1].cookTime'
The priority queue ensure that you get the least cooktime from given set

A working solution passing all cases written in python is given below for reference.

```
import heapq

def getAvgWaitTime(n, cust):
    heap = []
    curTime = 0
    waitTime = 0
    cust = sorted(cust)
    i = 0

    while i < n:
        if curTime < cust[i][0]:
            curTime = cust[i][0]
        while i < n and (curTime >= cust[i][0]):
            heapq.heappush(heap, (cust[i][1], cust[i][0]))
            i += 1

        while (i < n) and curTime < cust[i][0] and len(heap) > 0:
            time, wait = calculateWaiting(heap, curTime)
            curTime += time
            waitTime += wait

    # Clear all the jobs
    while len(heap) > 0:
        time, wait = calculateWaiting(heap, curTime)
        curTime += time
        waitTime += wait

    return waitTime / n


def calculateWaiting(heap, curTime):
    wait = 0
    cur = heapq.heappop(heap)
    wait = curTime - cur[1] + cur[0] 
    return (cur[0], wait)


n = int(raw_input().strip())
cust = []
for i in range(n):
    ar = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    cust.append((ar[0], ar[1]))


result = getAvgWaitTime(n, cust)
print result
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

First, a short explanation on important aspects of the problem.

1. Orders may not come in the right order, meaning they may not be sorted by arrival time. So, make sure to sort them by arrival time first.
2. It's important to realise that out of waiting orders, the cook must pick the one with the minimum cooking time. This way, the resulting waiting time will always be minimal.
3. Additionally, if there are no orders for the cook to process, the "current" time can be played out till the next arriving order.

### Code

In addition to the accepted answer, a `C++` solution (since the question is marked with a `C++` tag) may look as below.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct customer {
    uint64_t arrivalTime;
    uint64_t cookingTime;    
};

/*
 * Complete the minimumAverage function below.
 */
uint64_t minimumAverage(std::deque<customer> clients, uint32_t numberOfClients) {
    auto compareByArrivalTime = [](customer const &client1, customer const &client2)
            {
                return client1.arrivalTime < client2.arrivalTime;
            };
    
    auto compareByCookingTime = [](const customer &client1, const customer &client2)
            {
                return client1.cookingTime > client2.cookingTime;
            };
    
    std::sort(clients.begin(), clients.end(), compareByArrivalTime);
    
    std::priority_queue<customer, std::vector<customer>, decltype(compareByCookingTime)> clientPriorityQueue(compareByCookingTime);
    
    uint64_t minWaitingTime = 0;
    uint64_t currentTime = clients.front().arrivalTime;
    for (auto servedClient = 1; servedClient <= numberOfClients; servedClient++) {
        while (!clients.empty() && currentTime >= clients.front().arrivalTime) {
            clientPriorityQueue.push(clients.front());
            clients.pop_front();
        } 
        
        customer bestClient = clientPriorityQueue.top();
        clientPriorityQueue.pop();
        
        uint64_t arrivalTime = bestClient.arrivalTime;
        uint64_t cookingTime = bestClient.cookingTime;
        minWaitingTime += (currentTime - arrivalTime + cookingTime);
        currentTime += cookingTime;
        
        if (!clients.empty()) {
            currentTime = std::max(currentTime, clients.front().arrivalTime);    
        }
    }
    
    return minWaitingTime / numberOfClients;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::deque<customer> clients;
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        customer client;
        std::cin >> client.arrivalTime >> client.cookingTime;
        clients.push_back(client);
    }

    uint64_t result = minimumAverage(clients, n);

    std::cout << result << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```